# How did people estimate the speed of light before modern technology?

Tags: speed-of-light, measurements, history

I just read a wikipedia page on the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Early_history). Apparently people have made pretty accurate estimates for almost 200 years. How did they do this? How did they measure any fundamental constant accurately before they had modern technology?

Comment: Wikipedia's page on the speed of light not only discusses this but links to a separate page on the earliest experiment to produce a useful result.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Early_history

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a nice question about the history of science, not science itself.